# Is it possible to configure Nvidia GPU for caffe job only and embed intel GPU for xorg and others respectively?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia, xorg

My laptop has a Nvidia VC with 2G VRAM, and an embedded Intel VC, and the Nvidia VC is activated for using. The problem is that xorg and compiz use too much VRAM (900+ MB), and this causes caffe jobs are being out of memory frequently.

How would it be possible to activate two VCs at same time, but configure Nvidia VC for caffe job, and Intel VC for other jobs like Xorg, Compiz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that switching to intel gpu in Nivida X server settings will give what I want.